# Include all classes when reading from Zend_Session_Namespace?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-session

I have two namespaces in my session: "global" and "user"

In "global" there are just a few settings and in "user" i have a serialized user-object which I guess is saved correctly:
(This is from the sessionfile)

> global|a:16:{
>      [...]
>      s:12:"last_request";i:1301390173;
>      [...]
>   }
>
> user|a:1:{
>      s:10:"userObject";O:16:"currentUserModel":24:{
>          [...]
>          s:10:"*_roleId";s:7:"premium";
>          [...]
>      }
>   }

When I do this:
    `$sess = new Zend_Session_Namespace('global');`

I get an error about including "currentUserModel.php" which I don't want because I don't need the userobject at this point - all I want to do is get my "global" namespace.

Now the question is:
Do I have to include *all* classes for *all* objects stored in *all* my namespaces or is it possible to include just the classes for the objects that are in the namespace I'm accessing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using `user` to store `user` session?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. "user" is the namespace I made up. "userObject" is the session-variable and "currentUserModel" is the name of my class.

Comment: userObject and currentUserModel are saved in the user namespace or in the global namespace looking at you're error i suppose they are in the global namespace, another thing why are you saving the model in you're session ??

Comment: They _should_ be saved in the "user" namespace (I edited in a bigger part of the sesionfile). Because of your question I think I just need to save all the data from the userobject and create a new one with that saved data when I need it :) Would this be a good time to use the __sleep() and __wakeup() methods? (I'm pretty new to OOP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace in Zend_Session is just a layer on top of the $_SESSION global variable. In php, these namespaces don't exist. In Zend_Session, the namespace is a key from a associate array.

Thus, when you load a session namespace, you load in fact the whole $_SESSION, except you cannot access other "namespaces" through this Zend_Session. So yes: you need to include the file currentUserModel.php before the session.

Another method is to use properly the __sleep() and __wakeup() magic methods from the class to serialize only the properties of a class as an associative array and then you're afaik ready to go.